# Not able to use Prawn to generate PDF in Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, prawn

I am trying to generate a PDF from HTML in Rails using "prawn" gem, it works fine for the following case:

```
Prawn::Document.generate("hello.pdf") do
    text 'hello world'
end
```

But I want to use a **URL** instead of **text**, for example:

```
Prawn::Document.generate("hello.pdf") do
    url 'http://ourdesignzdev.info:3001/employee/resume/download?id=22'
end
```

But it doesn't work this way. How can I achieve this effect using a URL?

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"?

Comment: it shows an error like this "undefined method `url' for #<Prawn::Document:0x00000006a153c8> Did you mean? URI"

Comment: Usually an error like that means you're using your tool incorrectly. Are you sure `url` is a valid method? I don't see any reference to it [in the documentation](http://prawnpdf.org/api-docs/2.0/Prawn/Document.html).

Comment: but when i replace url with URI, then it doesn't show any error, but generates an empty pdf, i want to get data from the url i given

Comment: `URI` is a module, and parsing a URL using it returns an object that's simply ignored. It's not an error, but it's not usefl.

Comment: yes, that's why i am asking here, if anybody has any idea how to use this properly

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download arbitrary text to use, could always do that with this using [`open-uri`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html):

```
require 'open-uri'

Prawn::Document.generate("hello.pdf") do
  text open(...).read
end
```

Where `...` is the URL you want to read from.

Remember to check the documentation before trying things and expecting magic to happen. If you don't see something in the documentation you can always be hopeful and look at the source code for the module itself, there can be some fun surprises in there, but beyond that you'll have to do it yourself or ask for a patch from the author of the code.

Comment: it worked, but still it doesn't solve the problem completely, now the pdf show whole of the html, i don't want to see any html tag, how to remove it?

Comment: can you please just tell me how to remove html tags from the answer given

Comment: @tadman, you must provide a complete solution, if you know it then it would cost you nothing if you tell, otherwise there is no value of an incomplete answer.

Comment: @Insomania quoting the documentation directly: [*One thing Prawn is not, and will never be, is an HTML to PDF generator*](http://prawnpdf.org/api-docs/2.0/#label-Should+You+Use+Prawn-3F)

Comment: @sagarpandya82 ok i have used another tool i.e PDFkit, it works perfect, just a small issue is it doesn't show the content generated with jquery, like a range slider

Comment: @Insomania quoting the documentation: Resources aren't included in the PDF: Images, CSS, or JavaScript does not seem to be downloading correctly in the PDF. This is due to the fact that wkhtmltopdf does not know where to find those files. Make sure you are using absolute paths (start with forward slash) to your resources. If you are using PDFKit to generate PDFs from a raw HTML source make sure you use complete paths (either file paths or urls including the domain). In restrictive server environments the root_url configuration may be what you are looking for change your asset host.

Comment: @Insomania you'll have to work out what that all means, here is the [link to the docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/pdfkit/0.8.2#Troubleshooting)

Comment: I've answered your specific question. If Prawn isn't the right tool for the job, maybe you need to ask a whole other question.